# zsh in iTerm2 showing spaces in place of newlines

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, iterm2

I've been using iTerm 2 on a new MacBook for a couple of days with ZSH.

When I run a command which produces several lines of output, the second line appears to start after the end of the first.

For example, if I run `git help` in the iTerm 2 window, I get this; [image: Screenshot if iTerm2 showing git help output with broken line breaks]

While the same command, also in ZSH for the same user of the same computer, but in Terminal.app, gives this, which is what I'd expect (I've not configured colours and things, so don't worry about the lack of formatting);

[image: git help output from Terminal.app on the Mac.]

I've had real difficulty Googling for a problem, as it's difficult to find the words to describe this, but any solutions or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried creating a new profile in iTerm2, or alternatively, removing all of its settings with `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2`?

Comment: @slhck yes, that solves it. It's just odd, as none of the settings in the perferences view are different between the newly created profile and the old default "broken" one.

Comment: No idea here either… perhaps you can file a bug report and attach your iTerm2 preference files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this problem by creating a new profile, or resetting your iTerm 2 settings:

```
defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2
```